# Selenium: Click the text contain a link or href

Tags: selenium-webdriver

i want to do click function at the 'sign up' button, given below the screenshot regarding the screen. Likely i try several code but fail. Any code and suggestion really helpful to me.

Simple function when user click the text 'sign up' then the screen will redirect to sign up page.

[image]
[image]

---

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

since your provided html code isn't very helpful/detailed, I'd try these, both should work for your:

```
webdriver.findElement(linkText("Sign up")).click();

webdriver.findElement(xpath("//div[1]/a[contains(text(), 'Sign up')]")).click();
```

Comment: as my per research that my "main problem" is about the element call and added the time out element in my code are doing well. Just time out method its already deprecated.

Answer (score 0):

It's regarding the time out, @marek solution is not my main problem. My solution is to add the time out method so the application will not give any error due to cannot find an element and the driver already closed due to time out. There is unsufficient html code shown because I believe that is not the problem of the method like @marek method has shown.